# Reference DLL from Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Visual Studio code extension that has been developed in TypeScript and I would like to know if there is a way to reference methods from a DLL using Typescript. In this scenario, the DLL has logic to tokenize various elements in markdown files and I would like to leverage this logic instead of rewriting it.

I've used a library called [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for similar work in Python and I was wondering if anyone knows of a module for TypeScript or any native TypeScript functionality that I can leverage.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a TypeScript specific problem. It's more broadly a JavaScript one.

Take a look at [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/#how-to-integrate-c-code-into-nodejs-code)—specifically the section titled "How to: integrate c# code into Node.js code".

Using that you can load a .net assembly like so (code is lifted from their readme):

```
var clrMethod = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: 'My.Edge.Samples.dll',
    typeName: 'Samples.FooBar.MyType',
    methodName: 'MyMethod' // This must be Func<object,Task<object>>
});
```

If you're not using a .net assembly then you might be able to create a wrapper in .net to that library then reference that .net assembly in edge, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: Thanks David, much appreciated.  This helps out a lot.

Comment: Can you please explain with syntax? I do not know How to call this method (mymethod) from typescript file.

Comment: @GokulKumar see the referenced documentation in the section "How to: integrate c# code into Node.js code". I believe it's just `clrMethod(input, result => { });`